# Magento 2 - How to properly load quote model by quote id?

Tags: magento2, collection, model, quote, resource-model

I used to load the quote like this:

```
$quote = $this->quoteModel->load($quoteId);
```

But now I get a warning in PhpStorm saying that this method is deprecated:

> Deprecated:
> 100.1.0 because entities must not be responsible for their own loading. Service contracts should persist entities. Use resource model
> "load" or collections to implement service contract model loading
> operations.

So I tried it like this:

```
use \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote as QuoteResourceModel;

...

/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
 */
protected $quoteModel;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote
 */
protected $quoteResourceModel;

...

public function __construct(
    Quote $quoteModel,
    QuoteResourceModel $quoteResourceModel
) {
    $this->quoteModel = $quoteModel;
    $this->quoteResourceModel = $quoteResourceModel;
}

...

$quote = $this->quoteResourceModel->load($this->quoteModel, $quoteId);

$logger->info($quote->getId());  // empty
```

But `$quote->getId()` returns nothing, so it failed.

**Another Attempt:**

```
use \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory as Quote;
use \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;

...

protected $quoteModel;
protected $cri;

...

public function __construct(
    Quote $quoteModel,
    QuoteResourceModel $quoteResourceModel
) {
    $this->quoteModel = $quoteModel;
    $this->cri = $cri;
}

...

$q = $this->quoteModel->create();
$quote = $this->cri->load($q, $quoteId);

$logger->info($quote->getId());  // empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CartRepositoryInterface from Magento/Quote

Comment: There is no model called CartRepositoryInterface in module-quote/Model

Comment: Because it's an interface, \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface

Comment: You must use interface, instead of the concrete implementation every time you can

Comment: I tried it, but it still fails, I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: You aren't assign $cri variable, and if you look at the CartRepositoryInterface you will noticed that the method you need to use is ->get($quoteId) instead of ->load()

Comment: What do you mean with I am not assigning the variable? I replaced `load` with `get` and now it works :) thanks! I added the solution as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by applying the informations from @Matias answer:

He said that we should always use interface methods instead of the concrete implementation.

**Solution:**

```
use \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory as Quote;
use \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface as CRI;

...

protected $quoteModel;
protected $cri;

...

public function __construct(
    Quote $quoteModel,
    CRI $quoteResourceModel
) {
    $this->quoteModel = $quoteModel;
    $this->cri = $cri;
}

...

$quote = $this->cri->get($quoteId);
$logger->info($quote->getId());
```